# Set array order priority automatically in Collection

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting, collections

I have a Mongo collection with an array which contains a prio property.

```
{ "_id" : "zhkj", "title" : "List", "arraylist" : [ {"_id" : "xyz", "prio" : 1, "title" : Element 1"}, {"_id" : "abc", "prio" : 2, "title" : Element 2"}, {"_id" : "kjh", "prio" : 3, "title" : Element 3"} ] }
```

e.g. when I would like to remove the second element, my array would be [prio: 1, prio: 3]

So is there a way in Mongo to order the prio somehow automatically?
The result should be: [prio: 1, prio: 2]

Otherwise I would read the collection out and update the whole array manually in my application.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't support such operations out of box. You'll need to implement it in your application.

Comment: ok that's what I assumed. thanks.